# Test if the find command found files or not

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, find

I have a simple script to check a file of today's date. In the below example, the else condition is ignored if the file is not found. Why so?

```
if filedir=$(find . -type f -name "*.sql.gz"  -mtime -1 -printf "%f\n"); then
        echo $filedir
else
        echo "oops"
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Ljm Dullaart explained earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73080540/7939871), the `find` command does not return a specific code, when no file match patterns or rules.

Though, You may test it found a match, by checking the variable `filedir` is not empty:
`[ -n "${filedir}" ]`

```bash
if filedir="$(find . -type f -name '*.sql.gz'  -mtime -1)" && [ -n "${filedir}" ]; then
        printf 'Found: %s\n' "${filedir}"
else
        printf 'Oops! Found no file matching *.sql.gz!\n' >&2
fi
```

Comment: thanks but using the above code, even with the file exists, it returns no file found

Comment: If you are on a Macintosh OS, the `find` command has no `-printf`option. Removing this option would make it work.

Comment: much appreciated Lea. Works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

`find` returns an exit-code of 0 if all arguments are processed successfully, and has only a non-zero exitcode if there was an error. The exit code for `find` does not indicate whether or not files are found.

This is unlike, for example `grep`. You can see the difference in behaviour when you use

```
if filedir=$(find . -type f -name "*.sql.gz"  -mtime -1 -printf "%f\n" | grep '.'); then
```